# ¿Como cambiar el zoom de Chrome con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome

estoy intentando cambiar el zoom del navegador Chrome que aparece en este apartado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe alguna posibilidad de acceder a esa configuracion y cambiarla con Javascript?

Comment: Tal vez podrías acceder al estilo *zoom* de la siguiente forma `document.body.style.zoom = "80%";` **Ojo  esto no modifica la configuración del zoom del navegador**, pero podría servirte dependiendo el uso que quieras darle. ;)

Comment: Respuesta corta, [no se puede](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055365/12189493). Respuesta larga, puedes manipular el zoom del body como otros comentarios y respuestas sugieren.

Answer (score 1):

No afectará directamente la configuración del zoom del navegador, pero es un efecto muy parecido, podría ser algo así:

```
  function toggleZoomScreen() {
    document.body.style.zoom = "60%";
  }
```

o también:

```
document.body.style.transform = 'scale(2)';
```

o ir directamente con una `id` (el ejemplo lo vi de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130186/javascript-html-css-zooming/64473943#64473943)):

```
var zoomediv = document.getElementById('zoomediv')

var zoomin_button = document.querySelector('#zoomin')
zoomin_button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  zoomediv.style.zoom = '125%'
})

var zoomout_button = document.querySelector('#zoomout')
zoomout_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  zoomediv.style.zoom = '75%'
})
```